# Is user on page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I have site for example www.mysite.com, with a simple login system. I use PHP and MYSQL. In session I have:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']
```

Is possible to check if the user currently has the page `www.mysite.com/test.php` open?

I can use also jQuery and Ajax, but how?

In database I have for example:

```
Users:
id | username | is_on_test
1  | admin    | 0
2  | user     | 1
```

If user is on test.php I would like have in database in column is_on_test value 1, if isn't on test.php then should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call an ajax script every 20 or 30 secs or whatever frequency u like.
TEST.PHP

```
// fire below insertion to database
if (there exist any row of current logged in user on <table>)
    update <table> set time_stamp = Now() where user_id = $_SESSION['userid'] 
else
    insert into <table> (id,time_stamp) VALUES ($_SESSION['userid'],Now())
```

to display users list on ADMIN.PHP

```
//fire below query for displaying users 
select * from <table> where time_stamp in between 'Now()-20' and 'Now()+20'
```

make sure that the insertion / updation queries for insert / update timestamp in every ( 20 sec or whatever) interval

Comment: ok, but how check this if user close this page? your code add 1 to database only one and each open page. User can also open /other.php and test.php in two tabs in one browser.

Comment: what exactly u want to do. give abstract about ur problem ? r u making a list that display which users is on which page ?

Comment: ok. for that first check that the current page is test.php as i shown above (using PHP_SELF) then in the database add a column something like 'timestamp' when the user visits the page, an ajax function will fired every 30 secs, for updating that user's time .stamp. ( in short add / update the user_id's entry in database with current time ( in php use "Now" function) ) . and admin site make a query something like this "select * from <table> where time_stamp is in between 'Now-20' and 'Now+20'.

Comment: above query will list users that is on the page in between "Now()-20" and "Now()+20" values. here php "Now()" function gives the current system time stamp

Comment: answer is updated see above code. this is an example. it is logic, not exact sql query.

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits a page, in the header, you can check to see if `$_SESSION['user_id'];` exists. If it does, write the value stored in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to the database under that user's record. This will track the most current page they've landed on.

```
$sql = "Update users set lastPage='".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."' where id=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

More information on the `$_SERVER` array: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to check that the user has been on the current page?

If it's through the database, you can just write a function that inserts a users details and the page they were on into the database, from the $_SESSION data...

Comment: i dont know :) i find solution